# Facebook Graph API uploading videos

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

At work we have made a website where we can upload videos to facebook. We have encountered a problem; when a video is larger than 100MB, we get the following error: "An access token is required to request this ressource".

The access token is valid and we have no problems uploading videos below 100MB, so we are a bit puzzled why this happens.

I am using an Ajax post request with JavaScript/JQuery to upload the video.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("access_token", token);
    formData.append("id", "{page-id}");
    formData.append("title", $("#video_title").val());
    formData.append("description", $("#video_title").val());
    formData.append("source", $('#upload_btn').get(0).files[0]);
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{page-id}/videos";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (json) {
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).error.message);
        }
    });
```

Any ideas why we are getting this error message or should we be uploading a different way?

Comment: How long does the upload take? Maybe your access token expired in the meantime …?

Comment: The upload is taking a couple of minutes. but we are using a permanent access token, so this is not the issue,

Comment: As per docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads), non-resumable uploads should be fine for files up to 1 GB in size. There is also a mechanism for resumable uploads, to upload the video in chunks – but that is more complex to implement. I see no obvious reason, why an upload taking a couple of minutes and with a permanent access token should fail with this error … I’d suggest you file a bug report with Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @MikaelAndresen did you find any solution...?

Answer (score 2):

The API domain used is incorrect, for video uploads you should point to this domain: `https://graph-video.facebook.com/...`

Comment: how we can show progress bar during the facebook video upload can you suggest any approach please...  ?

Comment: how we can show progress bar during the facebook video upload can you suggest any approach please...  ?